# rabl have two subitems that I want to name differently

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rabl

I have a bit of a strange relationship where there is a combination that has a car_item and a part_item that are both of type item and my rabl looks like this:

```
object @l
attributes :id, :car_item, :part_item
```

If I do something like this (to return only a set of the attributes):

```
child :car_item do
  attributes :id, :header, :detail
end
```

It comes as:

```
"item":{
  "id":24,
  "header":"my header",
  "detail":"my detail"

}
```

I'd like to something like this:

```
child :car_item as :car_item do
  attributes :id, :header, :detail
end

child :part_item as :part_item do
  attributes :id, :header, :detail
end
```

How would I do this?

thx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this does it. doh...

```
child :car_item => "car_item" do
  attributes :id, :header, :detail
end
```

Comment: Yep that's it, glad you were able to answer your own question :)